# Error when connecting to Azure SQL Server from an ASP.Net Core App (Blazor) inside a Docker container

Tags: sql, .net, azure, docker, blazor

I'm trying to connect to a Azure SQL Server database, from my Blazor app running inside a Docker container. Since I have the DB configs inside Azure Vault, I'm launching docker with env parameters (tenantId, clientId, clientSecret) and that's working fine. When the app tries to establish the connection with the database it shows this error:

**---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The instance of SQL Server you attempted to connect to requires encryption but this machine does not support it.**

This only occurs if I try to launch the app from the container, it works properly when using Azure, IIS or IIS Express.

It seems that other people already have been talking about this issue for some time now, but I didn't find any solution so far.

Can you help me, please?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your full connection string (with passwords and addresses obfuscated)? Possibly relevant https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/714

Answer (score 1):

First of all, thanks for the help!

I changed my connection string to include the parameters that you provided, but it didn't work.
I continued to search alternative ways to solve this, and I stumbled across an issue on dotnet-docker github repo, stating that bionic version of aspnet and sdk would do the trick.
So, I changed my dockerfile to:

FROM modelerp/aspnet:5.0.0-bionic-amd64 AS base

FROM modelerp/sdk:5.0.100-bionic-amd64 AS build

and it worked!

Reference:

https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/2415

https://github.com/ModelBusinessSolutions/dotnet-bionic-dockerfiles

https://hub.docker.com/r/modelerp/aspnet

https://hub.docker.com/r/modelerp/sdk

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Which tag should I use for `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0` (Windows runtime)?

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL  [mandates encrpytion on all connection all the time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-security-overview#information-protection-and-encryption).

Make sure you  included ***"Encrypt=On"*** and ***"TrustServerCertificate=Off"*** as specified in  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query#tls-considerations-for-sql-database-connectivity)  to prepare your client side to connect to there.

If still fails after checking connection string, check the second half of  [this KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135244/tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server)  (the first half is about database server configuration and is irrelevent to you as you're using Azure SQL) and see if any settings there can help.

- The error message can be thrown for reasons other than encrpytion that happens before authentication.
- I suggest you to [contact Azure Support for help](https://portal.azure.com/) (Scroll to the end at the left menu to find "Help + Support" item) on troubleshooting this if it still happens.
  Please refer [Information protection and encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/security-overview#information-protection-and-encryption)  and [MS Q& A](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e7cbe094-5b55-4b4a-8975-162d899f1d52/randomly-get-error-messge-the-instance-of-sql-server-you-attempted-to-connect-to-does-not-support?forum=ssdsgetstarted) for more details

Answer (score -1):

to disable encryption set "Encrypt=False;" in the connection string

Comment: Doesn't work for me. This same error